# Create new columns in specific positions by row-wise summing other columns

Tags: awk

I would like to tranform this file, by adding two columns with the result of summing a value to another columns. I would like this new columns to be located next to the corresponding summed column.

```
 A        B     C 
2000    33000   2
2000    153000  1
2000    178000  1
2000    225000  1
2000    252000  1
```

I would like to get the following data

```
 A     A1    B     B1       C 
2000  2999  33000  33999    2
2000  2999  153000 153999   1
2000  2999  178000 78999    1
2000  2999  225000 225999   1
2000  2999  252000 252999   1
```

I have found how to sum a column: `awk '{{$2 += 999}; print $0}' myFile` but this transforms second column, instead of creating a new one. In addition, I am not sure about how to append that column in the desired positions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Sample specific answer:*** Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  $1=$1 OFS "A1"
  $2=$2 OFS "B1"
  print
  next
}
{
  $1=$1 OFS $1+999
  $2=$2 OFS $2+999
}
1
' Input_file | column -t
```

---

---

***Generic solution:*** Adding more generic solution, where we need NOT to write field logic for each field, just give field number inside variable `fieldsChange`(give only field number with comma separated) and even heading of it will be taken care. variable `valAdd` is having value which you need to add into new columns.

```
awk -v valAdd="999" -v fieldsChange="1,2" '
BEGIN{
  num=split(fieldsChange,arr,",")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){ value[arr[i]]       }
}
FNR==1{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
    if(i in value)   { $i=$i OFS $i"1"     }
  }
}
FNR>1{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
    if(i in value)   { $i=$i OFS $i+valAdd }
  }
}
1
' Input_file | column -t
```

Comment: What's the meaning of the last `1` in the command line? just before finishing the awk statement. Thanks!

Comment: @Jeni, `1` is one of the method of `awk` to print current line. `awk` works on method of `condition/pattern` then `action`. If any condition/pattern is true/matched then action mentioned after it will be performed; by mentioning `1` we are making condition true here and there is no action given here so by default print of current line will happen, cheers.

Answer (score 5):

```
awk '{
    # increase number of columns
    NF++
    # shift columns right, note - from the back!
    for (i = NF; i >= 2; --i) {
        $(i + 1) = $i
    }
    # increase second column
    $2 += 999
    # print it
    print
}
' myfile
```

And similar for 4th column.